# TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object HashingVectorizer

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp, countvectorizer

I have been facing this issue while fitting the dataset..Everything seems fine, don't know where the problem is.
Since I'm a beginner could anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong or am I missing something?

The problem seems to be in data preprocessing part

Error trace and the dataframe's head has been attached as image below
`

```
train = pd.read_csv('train.txt', sep='\t', dtype=str, header=None)
test =  pd.read_csv('test.txt', sep='\t', dtype=str, header=None)

X_train = train.iloc[:,1:]
y_train = train.iloc[:,0:1]

X_test = test.iloc[:,1:]
y_test = test.iloc[:,0:1]

TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC = '[A-Za-z0-9]+(?=\\s+)'

steps = [('vectorizer',HashingVectorizer(TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC,
                                                     norm=None, binary=False, lowercase=False,
                                                     ngram_range=(1,2))),
         ('clf',OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))]

pipeline = Pipeline(steps)
pipeline.fit(X_train,y_train)
accuracy = pipeline.score(X_test,y_test)
print(accuracy)
```

`

[stack trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIZJG.png) [dataframe head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I45T3.png)

Comment: Just check whether the dataset you are giving to hashing vectorizer has NULL value, i.e your X_train .If it has then remove it.I think your issue will resolve

Answer (score 0):

You need to define it like this:

```
steps = [('vectorizer',HashingVectorizer(tokenizer=TOKENS_ALPHANUMERIC,
                                         norm=None, binary=False, 
                                         lowercase=False,
                                         ngram_range=(1,2))),
         ('clf',OneVsRestClassifier(LogisticRegression()))]
```

When you do not specifiy the `key`, the value is taken for the first param in HashingVectorizer which is `input` and hence it was erroring.